# Why can't I catch this error in PHP (calling a function on a boolean)?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I had an issue that ultimately boiled down to not checking that a value was false before proceeding.

I tried to put a try/catch around it for debugging, but strangely that didn't help.

Here's a minimal example:

```
    try
    {
        $test = false;
        $test->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    catch (\Exception $e)
    {

    }
```

The error log shows that it's a fatal error. Does PHP have documentation on why this wouldn't throw a normal error?

Comment: try catch (Error $e) {... or for everything catch (Throwable $e) {...

Comment: @Philipp - My question is more about why that particular code throws an Error rather than an exception and whether it's documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does trigger "normal" error, but Errors aren't instance of `Exception`, they are separate branch of objects. Common ancestor for [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) and [`Error`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) is [`Throwable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) and you might want to use that.

Your catch block should look like

```
catch (\Throwable $e)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

or if you want to catch only Errors

```
catch (\Error $e)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Also note that prior to [PHP7 Errors and Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php) are two different things and are handler in different way. Errors can't be caught using try-catch block, you have to use error handler, check [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)